# PHP, cannot find syntax errors

Tags: php

**EDIT**: nvm, my bad, basically mis-read the errors reoported. Remember to check the dates and clear the logs wisely.

Apache's logs report errors in the lines 2,5 and 23, respectevely regarding unexpected "echo", "switch" and "echo" again.
I believe to already have checked every possible missing semicolon, but I still cannot find where the issues are.

Also, not sure if a semicolon should be added after the heredoc

```
<?php
if($_FILES){
$image = $_FILES['filename']['name'];

switch ($_FILE['filename']['type']) {
    case 'image/jpeg': $ext = 'jpg';
        break;
    case 'image/png': $ext = 'png';
        break;
    case 'iamge/gif': $ext = 'gif';
        break;
    default: $ext = '';
        break;
}
if($ext)
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['name'], "images/$image.$ext");
}

//$post_number = $post_number + 1;
$name = $_POST['name'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$text = echo <<<_END
<article>
    //<h3> '$post_number'</h3>
    <h4>'$name'</h4>
    <br>
    <p> '$comment' </p>
    <img src=images/'$image.$ext'>
</article>
_END;

$file = fopen("index.php", 'r+');
fseek($file, -17, SEEK_END);
fwrite($text);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: You don't need the `echo` when using heredoc syntax, looks ok other than that.

Comment: `echo` does not return anything http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: how/where is this file being used? is it being included in something else?

Comment: Yup, it's used by a form in another page

Comment: I think you meant `$text = <<<_END` instead of `$text = echo <<<_END`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of problems:

**1st:** Replace this line

```
$text = echo <<<_END
```

With this

```
$text = <<< "_END"
```

If you'd like to echo, do `echo $text` later. Also make sure that there is *nothing* other than `_END;` on the closing line. No tabs, no spaces before or after `_END;` ([see the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)).

**2nd:** Your `fwrite` will error because it needs the file handle, not just the text to write. While you're at it, you should check that the file was opened successfully before trying to write to it.  Replace your file operations with the code below:

```
if($file = fopen("index.php", 'r+')){
    fseek($file, -17, SEEK_END);
    fwrite($file, $text);
    fclose($file);
}else{/* Todo: handle fopen failure */}
```

Happy coding.